# How to apply combination fields validation using jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I my requirement form is generated dynamically. there are number of fields

```
<tr>    
    <td >Coding Guidelines</td>
    <td align="center">
     <select name="SELECT_TASK_1" id="SELECT_TASK_1">
       <option value="">Select</option>
       <option value="Y">Yes</option>
       <option value="N">No</option>
     </select>
   </td>
   <td align="center"><input type="text" size="10" name="COMP_DATE_1"></td>
  <td align="left">&nbsp;<textarea name="COMMENT_TASK_1" id="COMMENT_TASK_1" 
             cols="45" rows="4"></textarea><span id="COMMENT_ERROR_1" > </span>
   </td>
</tr>
```

there are number of TR generated base on DB rows. I want apply jquery validation on the combination of select No value and Comment field.

That means if select is No then comment is mandatory field.

Please help how to apply validation using Jquery validation plugin

Comment: which validation plugin are you using? i like this one: http://www.position-absolute.com/articles/jquery-form-validator-because-form-validation-is-a-mess/

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you can attach a handler to the submit form button:

```
$(#form-id).submit(function(){
var valid = true;
if($('#SELECT_TASK_1').val() == "N" && $('#COMMENT_TASK_1').val() == '')
valid = false;

return valid
});
```

For selecting all selects:

```
var selects = $('#form-id').find('select');
for(var i = 0; i < selects.length; i++){
  if(selects[i].val() == 'N'){
     if(area is empty)
      valid = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: this is happen only for first filed i want it to be for all the fields

Comment: You can always get all selects from the form and apply the same rule: $('form').find('select')....

Answer (score 0):

Here is a solution (though not very optimised):

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">select</option>
                <option value="1">yes</option>
                <option value="2">no</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea cols="10" rows="3"></textarea>
            <span id="COMMENT_ERROR_1"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>
            <select>
                <option value="0">select</option>
                <option value="1">yes</option>
                <option value="2">no</option>
            </select>
        </td>
        <td>
            <textarea cols="10" rows="3"></textarea>
            <span id="COMMENT_ERROR_1"></span>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
<input type="button" id="validate" value="validate"/>

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
    $("#validate").click(function(){
        $.each($("select"),function(){
            var n=$("option:selected",this).text();
            if(n=="no")
            {
                var $txt=$("textarea",$(this).closest("tr"));
                if($txt.text()=="")
                {
                    var $sp=$txt.parent().find("span");
                    $sp.text("Enter comment");
                }
                else
                {
                    var $sp=$txt.parent().find("span");
                    $sp.text("Enter comment");
                }
            }
        });
    });
});
</script>
```